# php convert array of object into associative array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

I am trying to do a bulk insert in laravel. My frontend post data to my laravel backend. The data that is posted looks like this:

```
rows[
0 {
  title: "my title",
  post: "my post text"
},
1 {
 title: "my title",
  post: "my post text"
},
2 {
 title: "my title",
  post: "my post text"
}
]
```

Now I wonder how I can make that into a associative array in laravel so it looks like this:

```
[['title'= >'my title','post'=>'my post text'],['title'= >'my title','post'=>'my post text']]
```

So it gets converted into a nameless array containing arrays with named keys

Comment: Please show how do you get the original array of objects.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what this question is about. I don't think you've really made up two different custom data formats for your internal use. If you already have a valid PHP array (as it seems) then you need to have keys. There's no such thing as keyless arrays.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I just call ``$model->insert($request->all());`` but the format must be like ``[['title'= >'my title','post'=>'my post text'],['title'= >'my title','post'=>'my post text']]`` and not like a object named "rows"

Comment: Please show results for `dd(request()->all());`

Comment: try `compact()`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin using ``$newAd->insert($request->input('rows'));`` worked